# Why \ added starting and ending when converting array to JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

when i tried to convert array in to JSON it converted perfect but \ added at start and ending side.
why ?

```
//code
var myJSON = "";
var FinalResult = JSON.stringify(result);
myJSON = JSON.stringify({"result": FinalResult});
document.write(myJSON);

//Output like
{"result":"[\"How are you?\"]"}

//require
{"result":"["How are you?"]"}
```

Comment: It may be escaping the inside double quotes.

Comment: Why are you stringifying twice?

Comment: When i try to display array format on document.write(FinalResult);
than it display plain text so first converted into stringify so it display array format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that you do two JSON.stringify

```
var FinalResult = JSON.stringify(result);
```

makes the string `["How are you?"]`
when you then make a object with the `{"result": FinalResult}` you just put the string in result property and when you then

```
JSON.stringify({"result": FinalResult});
```

it will escape the string that is FinalResult.

if you just do

```
JSON.stringify({"result": result});
```

you vill get `{"result":["How are you?"]}` which u can then simply parse back to object and with a property result which contains an array, otherwise as u have it now you will need to parse it twice to restore the old data.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way the `"` characters are escaped. It is okay, if you need not them to appear in final output - you should parse the string and replace them with smth.

Answer (score 2):

The '\' mark is added because you allready have a string in your JSON (myJSON), and when stringify.

You should try to put each character in array like

var myArray = ["How", "are", "you", "?"];
myArray.join().replace("," , " ");

Then you should stringify that array.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The backslash mark is added to tell the interpreter that " is part of the string and not the closing quotes.

Because json is built with quotes to separate keys and values, there's a need to separate this 2 types of quotes

Answer (score 1):

This is used to add a `"` inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're calling `JSON.stringify` twice. You're first converting `result` to JSON, and putting this in `FinalResult`; since it's a string, the JSON will begin with literal `"` characters.

Then you put `FinalResult` into the object `{result: FinalResult}`, and call `JSON.stringify` on this. This needs to escape those double quotes, so that they'll be treated as literals when you parse it.

As long as you reverse all the `JSON.stringify` calls with corresponding `JSON.parse` calls, everything should work properly.

```
myObject = JSON.parse(myJSON);
newResult = JSON.parse(myObject.result);
```